# Ошибка! Нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

В 10 строке ошибка

```html
var a,s,x,k:integer;
i:byte;

procedure proc (s: integer;var k:integer); 
begin
k:=3;
s:=1;

for var i:=1 to 4 do begin
    s:=s+power(-1,i)*power(x,i)*k; 
  k:=k+3;
end;
end;
begin
 writeln('введите X числo'); 
 readln(x,a);
 proc (x,a);
 writeln('summa=',s); 
end.
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что функция power возвращает real. На приводить к целому

Comment: @AlexeyTen а как правильнее тогда записать то? а то я не очень понимаю

Comment: @AlexeyTen можете кодом объяснить?

Comment: У вас ошибка на ошибке сидит... даже переписывать не хочется. вы ничего не считаете в процедуре, потому что `s` в ней параметр, так что ваша глобальная переменная `s` не получает никакого значения; даже если б получала - вы используете `power` не с теми типами, более того, это `power` совсем не нужно, как указал @MBo; вы передаете `a` как параметр `k`, но тут же его делаете равным 3 (может, так и надо по условию - его-то вы не показали), но зачем при этом вообще передавать параметром `a`? Пока хватит...

Answer (score 0):

Округлить до целого можно `round`, однако использование `power` в этой функции ни к чему.
Вы предполагали возвращение результата работы процедуры через глобальную переменную `s` - это большое зло. Лучше сделать функцию, возвращающую `s`, и `x` должно быть её параметром. Однако внутри функции `s` - локальный параметр, передаваемый по значению, и его изменение никак не отразится на внешней переменной.

Попробую исправить, однако непонятно, для чего нужен был параметр `a` - предположу, что это количество итераций.

```
function Calc(x, a: Integer): LongInt;
var
  i: Integer; 
  s: LongInt;
begin
  k := 3;
  s := 1;
  r := 1
  for i := 1 to a do begin
    r := - r * x;
    s := s + r * k; 
    k := k + 3;
  end;
  Result := s; { Calc := s в старом Паскале }
end;
```

Comment: А здесь нет возвращения через глобальную переменную, потому что `s` в процедуре не глобальное, а параметр...

Comment: @Harry Да, ещё хуже ;)

Answer (score 0):

Легче всего исправить, это строку  `s:=s+power(-1,i)*power(x,i)*k;` измениить на  `s:=s+Int(power(-1,i))*Int(power(x,i))*k;`